# What does "arr_##name" mean in C?

Tags: arrays, c

This question is quite specific to a block of code I am trying to understand on Code Signal:

````
```
// arr_##name alloc_arr_##name(int len) { //   arr_##name a = {len, len > 0 ? malloc(sizeof(type) * len) : NULL}; //   return a;
```
````

In fact, if there is a clear explanation of the "Definition for arrays" that would be immensely helpful. Working code below for adjacent elements product in C: Given an array of integers, find the pair of adjacent elements that has the largest product and return that product.

```
    // Definition for arrays:
    // typedef struct arr_##name {
    //   int size;
    //   type *arr;
    // } arr_##name;
    //
    // arr_##name alloc_arr_##name(int len) {
    //   arr_##name a = {len, len > 0 ? malloc(sizeof(type) * len) : NULL};
    //   return a;
    // }
    //
    //
    int solution(arr_integer inputArray) {
        int max = inputArray.arr[0] * inputArray.arr[1];
        for(int i=1; i<inputArray.size-1; i++) {
            int product = inputArray.arr[i] * inputArray.arr[i+1];
            if (max < product) max = product;
        }
        return max;
    }
```

Comment: `##` is used in macro definitions to concatenate tokens, notably to concatenate the result of replacing a macro parameter with other tokens. In this case, `name` is probably the name of a parameter of a macro defined with `#define`, but you have not shown the `#define` comment. You have only shown the text in comments. In comments, it is just comments and has no effect on compilation. If you want to understand the macro, show the code that actually defines the macro.

Comment: The symbols `arr_##name` appear in that code only in comments.  That combination otherwise would be erroneous in C, except under special circumstances such as the replacement text of certain function-like macros.

Answer (score 0):

The commented-out code fragments:

```
// typedef struct arr_##name {
//   int size;
//   type *arr;
// } arr_##name;
//
// arr_##name alloc_arr_##name(int len) {
//   arr_##name a = {len, len > 0 ? malloc(sizeof(type) * len) : NULL};
//   return a;
// }
```

must be part of the body of one or more macros, which might look like this:

```
#define ARRAY_TYPE(name, type) \
    typedef struct arr_##name { \
        int size; \
        type *arr; \
    } arr_##name; \
    \
    arr_##name alloc_arr_##name(int len) { \
        arr_##name a = {len, len > 0 ? malloc(sizeof(type) * len) : NULL}; \
        return a; \
    }
```

[The `##` operator](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.10.3.3) is a preprocessor operator (it can only appear validly in the body of a macro) that concatenates two tokens into a bigger one.

The macro might be used like this (note no training semicolon):

```
ARRAY_TYPE(shoes, double)
```

which would expand (give or take spacing) to:

```
typedef struct arr_shoes {
    int size;
    double *arr;
} arr_shoes;

arr_shoes alloc_arr_shoes(int len) {
    arr_shoes a = {len, len > 0 ? malloc(sizeof(double) * len) : NULL}; 
    return a;
}
```

Most people need pairs of shoes, hence the type `double`.

The code below your comments should have previously invoked:

```
ARRAY_TYPE(integer, int)
```

This creates the type `arr_integer` used in the code and creates the `alloc_arr_integer()` function that should have been used to create the value passed to the function `solution()`.

Answer (score 0):

```c
typedef struct arr_##name {
  int size;
  type *arr;
} arr_##name;
```

is not valid C. This will not compile.

---

However, `##` is meaningful in macros. It concatenates two tokens into one.

```c
#define foo( name ) arr_##name

foo( bar )
```

is equivalent to

```c
arr_bar
```